# Memory relocation for vector across DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, dll

**This question is not a duplicate to those with a similar name in SO**

> It is well-known that if DLLs are statically linked (/MT flag in
>   MSVC), the DLL that has allocated the memory MUST deallocate it; otherwise
>   memory deallocation will cause runtime errors.

Here is the problem:

- I have allocated a `std::vector` in DLL, say `A`.
- `A` passes the vector to DLL, say `B`.
- DLL `B` inserts data into the vector.
- Now, if DLL `A` tries to destruct the vector, it will face errors.

I have figured out that if I use `std::vector::reserve` before passing the vector to `B`, to have the vector big enough to hold the data and prevent memory reallocation - that normally happens during item insertion - then I won't get errors in `A` when trying to destruct the vector. It seems that, in case of memory reallocation, `B` allocates for the vector in its own heap. Is my reasoning wrong?  How can I prevent this?

Comment: avoid using static linking of c++ runtime

Comment: another option - override an allocator for this vector using windows heap

Comment: @Serge I have to use static linkage to make a standalone executable. Do you know of any example for such a custom allocator? I've tried to write custom allocators before but it was not that easy. thank you

Comment: You already using a `DLL`, that contradicts your statement on standalone executable. No, unfortunately, I do not know one. I would search the internet should I need one.

Comment: @Serge Using DLLs does not necessary implies that the executable won't run. It will actually function without them. By standalone I mean not to force the user to install C++ Runtime before/after installation. Yes, I've searched but materials on `custom allocators` are either too verbose or unrelated. BTW, why would I need to avoid static linkage?

Comment: Because the purpose of DLL's and so's is to make use of RAM more efficient. The convenience of installation not in the number of files an installer should copy to the target system, but in transparency for a user, i.e. the installer of your DLL should also install all necessary dependencies. Do you think your DLL is the only one using C++ on a target system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way round this is to hide the `vector` inside methods exposed from the dll so you can get a `const vector` to view in other dlls, but not modify it. Then create a new function in dll B that adds the entry to the vector on the caller's behalf.

So your `vector` remains hidden inside dll B for all modifications.

Comment: If you go to these lengths, wouldn't it make more sense to have a "shadow vector class" which uses the function in DLL B you mention? I.e. to the user of the vector class it'd appear as if it's a normal vector.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Your idea is great. Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to implement a mix of your ideas. Thank you both. If I faced any odds I'll edit my question to give a better insight to those who may face the same problem latter.